# Adjusting a column value by subtracting previous running total from current row value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, common-table-expression

I have worked on this issue and looked for similar threads but could not find any solution yet.

I have tried couple ways which i will explain and give an example of the data and what needs to be achieved:

I have a table that looks like this :

[image]

Code:

```
drop table if exists #temp

create table #temp 
(
     col1 varchar(10), 
     col2 varchar(10),
     col3 varchar(10), 
     [date] date,
     dateindex int, 
     totals money, 
     adjustement money 
)

insert into #temp 
values ('customer1', 'customer1', 'customer1', '01-01-2020', 1, 0, 100),
       ('customer1', 'customer1', 'customer1', '01-02-2020', 1, 0, 200),
       ('customer1', 'customer1', 'customer1', '01-03-2020', 1, 50, 0),
       ('customer1', 'customer1', 'customer1', '01-03-2020', 2, 100, 0),
       ('customer2', 'customer2', 'customer2', '01-04-2020', 1, 0, 150),
       ('customer2', 'customer2', 'customer2', '01-05-2020', 2, 0, 300),
       ('customer2', 'customer2', 'customer2', '01-06-2020', 1, 50, 0),
       ('customer2', 'customer2', 'customer2', '01-06-2020', 2, 100, 0)
```

We have two numeric columns: `totals` and `adjustments`, the rest is unique attributes for a customer and a date.

When adjustments is different from 0, that is fine and we don't need to change those numbers.

When totals is different from 0, that is when I want to do a calculation and hopefully update the result of the `Adjustments` column in the same row (when total is <> 0, adjustments is always = 0).

The calculation to replace those 0 adjustments should be : the current total value - all previous adjustments (running total)

This is what I have tried :

```
select 
    *,
    case 
       when totals <> 0 
           then totals - sum(adjustement) over (partition by col1,col2,col3  
                                                order by [date] asc, dateindex asc 
                                                rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) 
           else adjustement 
    end as 'Calculation'    
from
    #temp
```

[image]

Row 3 returns the correct result : 50 - 300 = -250

Now, when you have totals on the same day (row 3 and 4 ), same date but different index (index used to know which transaction came first), the window function is doing row4 = 100 -(100+200+0) =-200 when it needs to be 100 - (100+200-250+0) = 50 .

The previous -250 is not included because its not the actual data .I need to find way to update the table while doing the calculation so that -250 can be updated on the table before moving the next row.

This calculation is done for each customer and that is why I am partitioning by customer columns.

I really appreciate any hints or advice on this and what could be the best approach

Thanks !

Comment: why row 1 and 2 are positive value when your formula is `the current total value - all previous adjustments` ?

Comment: Do you mean to put the `case when` on the *inside* of the `sum`?

Comment: This is really strange.  How many values might you have on the same day?

Comment: Squirrel , because of the else condition. it justs puts what is already there .

Comment: @GordonLinoff Not more than 3 totals on the same day. and they are always indexed 1,2,3 .

Comment: @usefjuan . . . Your sample data doesn't show the index.

Comment: @Charlieface the sum() over  does a running total. so at row 3 , the running total for adjustments would be 300, therefore   50 - 300 = 250 
row 4 : running total as per the function (100+200+0) = 300  , therefore 100 - 300 = -200
the issue is i want to pick up the -250 value as well for ROW 4

Comment: @GordonLinoff oh sorry let me update it now

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how the third index would work on a date.  But for the second index (as in your example), you can do the calculation twice:

```
select t.* ,
       (case when totals <> 0 and dateindex = 2
             then totals - sum(calculation) over (partition by  col1, col2, col3
                                                  order by date, dateindex
                                                  rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                                 )
             else calculation 
        end) as Calculation_2   
from (select t.*,
             (case when totals <> 0 and dateindex = 1
                   then totals - sum(adjustement) over (partition by col1,col2,col3  
                                                        order by [date] asc,dateindex asc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) 
                   when dateindex = 1 then adjustement 
              end) as Calculation   
      from temp t
     ) t;
```

I suspect the third calculation just requires another level of subquery.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c099a6/9) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: i did some change to the subquery : Removed when 'dateindex = 1 then adjustement'  and replaced with 'ELSE adjustement '.
It is working  and we have two columns with separate results.
my other point above is there any way we can update those value while continuing to do the calculation? because ultimately those values need to be updated on the same table

Comment: @usefjuan . . . In the end, you can make this all a CTE and update the CTE.  That is one of the nifty features of SQL Server.